# convert json to const char on iphone for sqlite

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, sqlite, nsdictionary

I am having an issue storing some json data I am downloading. The issue I think is the converting from string to json and then to const char. There maybe a better way of doing this also. here is what I have

```
 NSDictionary *jsonAll = [[(NSString *)response uppercaseString] JSONValue];
//Get the objects within the seat number object


NSDictionary *seatInfo = [jsonAll objectForKey:seatMessage];

//Split the objects up accoridng to the track information -- we will have to structure  
//we havethe maeesge with how ever many track

NSMutableString *Track1 = [seatInfo objectForKey:@"TRACK1'];
NSMutableString *Track2 = [seatInfo objectForKey:@"TRACK2"];
```

The json file I am bringing in looks like this

```
{A1 =     {
    TRACK1 =         (
        1462527,
        1462527,
        1462527,
        1462527,
        1462527,
        1462527,
        1462527,
        1462527,
        1462527,
        1462527,
        1462527
    );
    TRACK2 =         (
        12800016,
        12800016,
        12800016,
        12800016,
        12800016,
        1462527,
        12800016,
        12800016,
        12800016,
        12800016,
        12800016
    );
};
```

}

I think the issue is the new lines. When I try store the data in sql I have to convert it to a const char as far as I know.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You apparently didn't read the comments on your previous query -- `[seatInfo objectForKey:@"TRACK1']` returns an NSArray, not an NSMutableString.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting Json objects and array IOS in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248326/splitting-json-objects-and-array-ios-in-sql)

Comment: NSarray gives me the same error. I am getting the right info and splitting it up. But the issue now is that I am trying to change that string or array into a char to store it into sql

Comment: Try reading the spec for NSString.  And search the web for some examples of how others do SQLite operations from Objective-C.

Comment: BTW: What's in that NSArray will be a bunch of NSNumber objects which you must then convert into integers.  You've got to decide how you want to write the integers into SQLite -- as individual items, or a list in a string, or a blob, or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDictionary *jsonAll = [[(NSString *)response uppercaseString] JSONValue];
```

//Get the objects within the seat number object

```
NSDictionary *seatInfo = [jsonAll objectForKey:seatMessage];
```

//Split the objects up accoridng to the track information -- we will have to structure
//we havethe maeesge with how ever many track

```
NSArray *Track1 = [seatInfo objectForKey:@"TRACK1'];

for(id str in Track1)
{
   //save the strings in database   
}
```